# NFS Ownership/Permissions

Tags: permissions, nfs, chown, dd-wrt

I'm trying to get NFS working properly on a DD-WRT install using [OTRW2](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OTRW2_%28Optware_the_right_way_Take_2%29). I can see and mount the share from the client. But when I do, the mounted folder changes it's owner to `root:root` and so my normal user does not have write access.

I saw [this post](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=521112#521112) by Frater (the original author of the scripts), in which he says that the `unfsd` service is running as `www-data:www-data` and that the share should be `chown`ed.

However when I try `chown`ing the `/mnt` symlink or the `/tmp/mnt` mount, I receive the following:

```
root@router:~# sudo chown www-data:www-data /mnt 
changing ownership of `/mnt': Operation not permitted 
root@router:~# sudo chown www-data:www-data /tmp/mnt 
changing ownership of `/tmp/mnt': Operation not permitted
```

My `mount`s look like this:

```
root@router:/opt# mount 
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw) 
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro) 
none on /dev type devfs (rw) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw) 
ramfs on /tmp type ramfs (rw) 
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw) 
devpts on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw) 
/dev/discs/disc0/part1 on /opt type ext3 (rw,noatime,data=ordered) 
/dev/sda3 on /tmp/mnt type vfat rw,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1)
```

I've tried the default `exports` file as well as this:

```
root@router:~# cat /opt/etc/exports                                  
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported 
#      to NFS clients.  See exports(5). 
# 
/mnt       192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash)

# default
#/mnt       192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0(rw,no_root_squash)
```

On the client I have a directory that starts out as:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 kyle users   4096 Feb 16 09:43 NAS
```

I've tried from the command line:

```
kyle@client:~$ sudo mount -v -t nfs router:/mnt NAS 
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Feb 16 14:09:17 2014 
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.117' 
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported 
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.1' 
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6 
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049 
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17 
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 2049
```

And with various `fstab` lines:

```
# router NAS mounting 
router:/mnt           /home/kyle/NAS             nfs      auto      0 0 
#router:/mnt           /home/kyle/NAS             nfs      rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,_netdev,nfsvers=3   0 0
```

But the folder always ends up as:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   16384 Dec 31  1969 NAS
```

What do I need to do to make the NFS share writable from the client side?

Comment: I think your problem is that the file system on /dev/sda3 is vfat (fat). vfat does not support linux permissions.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Okay. So my options are stick with `vfat` and use Samba (which I've had working before) or reformat as `ext` so I can use NFS? Suggestion/opinion on best combination for use in a mixed OS environment?

Comment: In a mixed OS environment, I would use samba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change permissions on this mount:

> /dev/sda3 on /tmp/mnt type vfat rw,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1)

Notice the type is VFAT. You can only change permissions using `chmod` on EXT type permissions, or ones that actually support it.

You can either reformat it as EXT4, `mkfs.ext4`, or using something like Samba to provide access to it the underlying `/tmp/mnt`.